# Create a NodeJS KeyObject from a string

Tags: node.js, next.js, jwt, cryptography, jose

How do I create a NodeJS Crypto KeyObject from the randomish string in my .env file?

I was using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to create/verify JWTs, but it can't run in nextjs middleware edge functions, so I want to migrate to using [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose). The problem is that in jose you can't sign a JWT with a secret string from your .env file, you need to create a cryptographic KeyObject and use that to sign the JWT.

```
// example env file
JWT_SECRET=Swe4g7c?UBm5Nrd96vhsVDtkyJFbqKMTm!TMw5BDRLtaCFAXNvbq?s4rGKQSZnUP
```

I tried to create a KeyObject with the API below, but I got an error from jose:

```js
import crypto from 'crypto'; 
const key = crypto.createSecretKey(process.env.JWT_SECRET, 'utf-8'); 
const jwt = new jose.SignJWT(payload).sign(key); 

// Error: KeyObject or CryptoKey instance for asymmetric algorithms must not be of type "secret."
```

I also tried to use a Uint8Array, since the [jose docs](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/6e0a591e30176ee5082bb1a7046543154fc40af0/docs/classes/jwt_sign.SignJWT.md#sign) say I can, but I get this error:

```js
const key = new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.JWT_SECRET);
const jwt = new jose.SignJWT(payload).sign(key); 

// Error: Key must be one of type KeyObject or CryptoKey. Received an instance of Uint8Array.`
```

Thanks in advance for any help, comments, links, resources!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is setting the JOSE protected header with an appropriate symmetric JWS algorithm (alg).

The [example](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/classes/jwt_sign.SignJWT.md#readme) show how that's done and the appropriate symmetric algorithm is HS256.

```
import * as jose from "jose";

const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(
  "Swe4g7c?UBm5Nrd96vhsVDtkyJFbqKMTm!TMw5BDRLtaCFAXNvbq?s4rGKQSZnUP"
);

const jwt = await new jose.SignJWT({ foo: "bar" })
  .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
  .sign(secret);
console.log(jwt); // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ.iPFY1ibZc5dTBzRD46ma-Du0avf20nYKtQQsgnyf7ZM
```

Comment: Thank you! Your example link shows an example using `ES256`, not `HS256`, so I'm wondering how you found that option. I was using ES256, and it obviously was not working.

Comment: I found this demo on a Vercel Github page that shows the implementation I was/am trying to accomplish: https://github.com/vercel/examples/blob/main/edge-functions/jwt-authentication/lib/auth.ts

Comment: Final note: To anyone running this in a NextJS middleware (edge function), crypto is not supported (at least, not right now). Use the TextEncoder to create a Uint8Array.

Comment: Those are standard JOSE algorithm identifiers. [here](https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/114) a general overview. [here](https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/210) algorithm specific requirements on the key/secret.

None of this is proprietary to the `jose` library, it merely implements the JOSE family of specifications.